# Creating crash dumps and stack traces in in Java

Tags: java

In my Java application I have a few `try` `catch` exception blocks where I'm trying to trap my exceptions. Many of them are handled and therefore totally transparent to the user but I'd like to create a dump file containing the value of variables and the entire call stack so that I can diagnose what caused this issue. Is this possible? A block of code didn't work as it was supposed to althought all looks fine in the front I'd like to debug the application with these dump files.

So far, i've done without anything like this and it's almost impossible to pinpoint what caused the error.

Thanks.

Comment: This is what a debugger does. In your IDE it next to the "Run" button.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some logging framework for such task. I normally use this: [Apache Log4J](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html) and [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/). You can log variable values just before logging exceptions that you think can cause the problem.

Comment: I've been using the logging framework extensively but a full-fledged memory dump is a whole different story. I can't debug my program using the log files. I've read that with the memory dumps, one could debug the program state as it was.

Comment: You can log variable values in file just before logging exception. In that way you can see variable values. I'm not sure this is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to look at is your stack dump, which is very helpful in diagnosing some problems. Try sending a QUIT signal (by pressing Ctrl-\ in terminal, or kill command) to your Java process.

You can also set up JVM to do a heap dump when a memory error occurrs, by passing -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError option in the command line. Once you do this, try raising an OutOfMemoryError in your code in the right moment.

Comment: Try Ctrl-Break (instead of Ctrl-\\) in MS Windows.

Comment: This is not what I meant. I should have been more explicit. You see, when I've published my desktop application to users, I'd like to save something like a memory-dump/application-state when an internal error occurs. The user would see a message like "An internal error has occurred." and the dump file could be sent to me so I can investigate what caused the error. What you're getting at, as I have understood, is when developing, if if my application crashes, I can inspect the dump file. Right? Thanks.

Comment: You can make a heap dump on demand, using some JVM utilities, but they need to be called from another (parent perhaps) process and they require to be installed on user's machine in the first place. Something like this might help you: jmap -heap:format=b -d64 <jvm pid>

Comment: See here: http://javaworks.wordpress.com/2009/12/03/jvm-heap-dumps-generation-and-analysis/

Comment: Generally speaking, I would catch everything (that might have escaped) in the main code block and log a full stack trace.